# Which is better, Doing data manipulation using SQL Queries or manipulating the data in an Array in php?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, comparison, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use a query or code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843307/when-to-use-a-query-or-code)

I have a large database of users and their details. I want to find all the people that are most similar to each other.
Which way is preferable for comparison ?
Directly writing SQL queries such that they do manipulation within database to retrieve a filtered (matched) record. OR
Retrieving the raw data first in an array in php & then applying comparison operations on that array ?
Lets say I have 1000 users, and I want to find the people with most mutual friends.

```
UserA has {a,b,r,c,g,h,r,q,l}
UserB has {x,y,z}
UserC has {a,c,r,g,q}
.
.
.
UserN has{x,y....n}
```

So I want to find the users with the most mutual friends with that of UserA.
Such as comparing each element of UserA to all the elements of all the user arrays from whole database ? In the above case UserC should be the most similar user to UserA.
I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: It really depends on the the type of grouping/manipulation you want to do, the hardware you are running it on, and where you are technically most sound at.

Comment: Generally the RDBMS is already highly optimized to do this work. With proper indexing it can be far more efficient on to perform in the query. And if the database resides on another machine, you decouple the  data processing load from the front-end access load.

Comment: As with any _is x faster than y_ question though, the only real answer is to benchmark it for yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by better? Faster on the machine? Faster by developer time?

Comment: Logically, you have to use database. It is better in performance, because finally every piece of data will be retrieved from the database so recalling it formatted using the SQL is better and faster and prevent repeating the logic.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to have the query at the backend/database level so your data retrieval endpoints can be used by multiple apps and for a single point of maintenance when database schema changes are made that require your query and/or stored procedures to change. I am certain there are other benefits to this approach.

Comment: @Idav1s , I mean faster in performance wise. Such that my php code does not take forever to load. OR viceversa the mysql database should retrieve the result in an efficient and responsive time.

Comment: I voted as Not Constructive. This sort of question is *not* very suitable on SO without one (or both) *working implementations*; these provide a base-line of required information in "performance between" questions. (However, heed the comments: don't throw out 40+ years of relational design and optimization without good cause!)

Comment: @gh9 , In my case I need to find the duplicates records of userID_1 with all other users in database. Since I need to find the people with most similarities. The database may contain records in thousands.

Comment: @Faizan There won't be any *less* records/data in PHP so that argument is invalid by itself. Instead of questioning performance, consider this: How *could* one write a query to do with in SQL? What restrictions does such an SQL approach have? What requirements on indices/relations does are there for good performance using said approach? What the the bounds/complexity of such a query and, could they be reduced with a special algorithm (in PHP)?

Comment: @pst Since both the database & the php array both have to process the same amount of data. Which is a better approach to manipulate for faster performance? Yeah thats true ^ so does that mean it depends upon the type of data manipulation to be done?

Comment: @Faizan Which approach has the better complexity? Assuming that complexity is identical, which approach has a better/lower constant? And then, finally, which approach *has the better wall-clock time*? ;-) Performing calculations client-side generally requires transferring all the initial data and not just the resulting data: as the number of records scales so does the data needing to be transferred before calculations can even begin!

Comment: @pst So you mean to say that manipulation within SQL queries are preferable rather than manipulations inside php coding. since we want to reduce the transfer time.

Comment: @Faizan That is one thing to consider. However, as the number of records grows it is the *computational complexity* of both approaches that is of utmost importance. At this stage, however, getting *something that works* is more important.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you represent friendships in a table like this:

```
Table: friendships
from_id  |  to_id
----------------------------
      a  |      a
      a  |      b
      a  |      r
      a  |      c
 ...etc...
      b  |      x
      b  |      y
      b  |      z
 ...etc...
```

Now you can write a query to answer your question (tested in MySQL):

```
SELECT user_id AS user_id_with_most_common_friends, MAX(cnt) AS number_of_common_friends FROM 
  (SELECT f2.from_id AS user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM friendships f1
   JOIN friendships f2 ON (f1.to_id = f2.to_id AND f2.from_id <> 'a')
   WHERE f1.from_id = 'a'
   GROUP BY f2.from_id) totals;
```

As to the performance question, empirical testing in your specific situation will give the most reliable answer, but for a large database I would expect using the above SQL query to be much faster than querying every row and calculating the results in PHP, for these reasons:

1. If from_id and to_id are indexed, the RDBMS may not need to touch every row
2. Returning all records will ensure you touch every row and cause the php code to consume a lot of memory (which adds some overhead for memory allocations, and will slow things to a deadly crawl if you run out of RAM).
3. Once your php code has the data, it will not likely be able to perform the individual steps of the computation any faster than SQL could.

Unless your php code has something up its sleeve to compensate for these disadvantages (like an algorithm with lower complexity that cannot be expressed in SQL, or calling out to some specialized C code, e.g. image processing), it's typically going to be faster to keep the work inside the RDBMS as much as possible.

Comment: In my case , I am doing this for my project of 'Data Structures' & the main requirement of this course is to use data structures for manipulating data. I know these things can be done using SQL queries. Can you recommend me what sort of data structure would be applicable to my scenario where I have these things to compare to find similar people, People product wants, people mutual friends, people followers, people common answers to specific questions etc. I have all these things in my database in form of tables.Which data structure could be used I am confused.

Comment: As a hint I would suggest storing the data in such a way that you can efficiently look up a person X and then be able to efficiently answer the following questions about X: (1) list everyone that X likes (2) given person Y, does X like Y? (3) list everyone that likes X (4) given person Y, does Y like X?